# How the unity container will resolve the registered service

Tags: mvvm, unity-container, prism

In my code I am trying to log the viewModel name on entry/exit of a viewModel.

My logger is

```
public interface ILoggerService : ILoggerFacade
{
    void LogMessage(string message );       
    void LogEntry();   
    void LogExit();
}

public class LoggerService : ILoggerService
{
    public void LogEntry()
    {
        var trace = new StackTrace();
        if (trace.FrameCount > 1)
        {
            string ns = trace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace;
            string typeName = trace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
            string message = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2} Entry", ns, typeName,
                                            trace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
            LogDebug(message, DefaultPriority);
        }
    }

    //  Same for LogExit
}
```

My Bootstrapper

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterInstance<ILoggerService>(_logger);
    }
    protected override ILoggerFacade CreateLogger()
    {
        _logger = new LoggerService();
        return _logger;
    }
}
```

My ViewModel & Model are

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    private readonly ILoggerService _loggerService;
    private readonly HomeModel _model;
    public HomeViewModel(HomeModel model, ILoggerService logger)
    {
        logger.LogEntry();
        _model = model;
        _loggerService = logger;

        // Do some other stuff here.

        logger.LogExit();
    }
}

public class HomeModel
{
    private ILoggerService _logger;
    public HomeModel(ILoggerService logger)
    {
        logger.LogEntry();
        _logger = logger;
        logger.LogExit();
    }
}
```

Error I got

```
Cat[Critical} Sev[Critical] Pri[100] Framework Time:[ 2016-09-22  13:33:39.860] Shisha.exe PId: 22220 ThreadId:7428 
 ####   An exception occurred while initializing module 'MainModule'. 
    - The exception message was: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Modules.Main.Views.HomeView", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Modules.Main.Models.HomeModel(Services.Logging.Interface.ILoggerService logger).
Exception is: NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Modules.Main.Views.HomeView,(none)
  Resolving parameter "viewModel" of constructor Modules.Main.Views.HomeView(Modules.Main.ViewModels.HomeViewModel viewModel)
    Resolving Modules.Main.ViewModels.HomeViewModel,(none)
    Resolving parameter "model" of constructor Modules.Main.ViewModels.HomeViewModel(Modules.Main.Models.HomeModel model, Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionManager regionManager, Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.IEventAggregator eventAggregator, Services.Dialogs.Interface.IDialogService dialogService, Services.Logging.Interface.ILoggerService logger, Services.Localisation.Interfaces.ITranslator translator)
      Resolving Modules.Main.Models.HomeModel,(none)
      Calling constructor Modules.Main.Models.HomeModel(Services.Logging.Interface.ILoggerService logger)

    - The Assembly that the module was trying to be loaded from was:Modules.Main, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception occurred while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help locate the root cause of the problem. 
     at Services.Logging.LoggerService.LogCritical(String message, Int32 priority) in C:\Projects\Utilities\DotNet\Services\Services.Logging\LoggerService.cs:line 257
   at Services.Logging.LoggerService.LogCritical(String message) in C:\Projects\Utilities\DotNet\Services\Services.Logging\LoggerService.cs:line 250
   at Shisha.Bootstrapper.InitializeModules() in C:\Projects\Shisha\Application\Shisha\Bootstrapper.cs:line 85
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.Run(Boolean runWithDefaultConfiguration)
   at Shisha.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Shisha\Application\Shisha\App.xaml.cs:line 39
   at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at MyApp.App.Main() in C:\Projects\Shisha\Application\Shisha\obj\x86\Release\App.g.cs:line 0
```

I Googled and debugged ( by adding logs ) a lot finally came to know that it is the

```
"trace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace;"
```

that is failing..

It working fine in 'Debug' mode ( because of PDB file ) but is failing in 'Release' mode.

Instead of resolving the logger from constructor if we use

```
Resolve<ILoggerService>(),
```

it is working fine.

It is not clear for me how `_container.Resolve()` got the `MethodBase` information and 'resolving from constructor' didn't.
Can anyone explain  me what is the difference between these two.

OR

Am I completely missing something?

Comment: Well, it seems there is some pertinent code that you are not showing.  For instance, the stack trace shows that an exception occurred in `Services.Logging.LoggerService.LogCritical(String message, Int32 priority)`.  You are not showing that method and your `ILoggerService `  interface does not declare that method either.  Presumably, this method relies on some object that is null.  Hence the `NullReferenceException`.  That is my best guess based on what I can see.

Comment: Thank you Jason for looking into it. My ILoggerInterface has several methods including LogCritical. When the application is about to crash I am using LogCritical() to log into the file. BUt the application is closing at LogEntry().

Comment: Latest update is, below code is working in release mode. May be the compiler is doing something behind                                         [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]                                                                 public class HomeModel
{
    private ILoggerService _logger;
    public HomeModel(ILoggerService logger)
    {
        logger.LogEntry();
        _logger = logger;
        logger.LogExit();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems the compiler is converting the constructor to inline constructor.

By using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` and telling the compiler not to inline is working fine.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] 
public class HomeModel 
{ 
  private ILoggerService _logger; 
  public HomeModel(ILoggerService logger) 
  { 
    logger.LogEntry(); 
    _logger = logger; 
    logger.LogExit(); 
  } 
}
```